# Como ter seu site destacado do lado direito no Google

Tags: html, google

Pesquisei pelo termo "brainstorm9" no Google, e percebi que o **Google** deu um destaque do lado direito da página, para a página do G+ do site. Achava que ali, havia apenas informações do Wikipedia.

Vejam a imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A minha pergunta é:
Preciso mudar algo no `<head>` da minha página, incluir alguma `meta` para que minha própria página no G+ aparece ali? Ou o Google faz isso sozinho?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pra aparecer ali, você precisa [pagar ao Google pelo privilégio](http://www.google.com.br/intl/ALL_br/adwords/index.html?sourceid=awo&subid=br-pt-ha-aw-bhrh0~42667966735&gclid=CMLF6vqTxcACFQQT7Aodr1gARw). O serviço se chama AdWords.

Vale a pena [ler o FAQ](http://www.google.com.br/intl/ALL_br/adwords/how-it-works/faq.html?sourceid=awo&subid=br-pt-ha-aw-bhrh0~42667966735&__utma=248742289.1593397922.1409750916.1409750916.1409751069.2&__utmb=248742289.3.9.1409751076435&__utmc=248742289&__utmx=-&__utmz=248742289.1409751069.2.2.utmcsr=br-pt-ha-aw-bhrh0~42667966735|utmccn=awo|utmcmd=(not%20set)&__utmv=-&__utmk=100847234) antes de decidir se vale o custo-benefício.

Comment: Tinha encontrado esse link anteriormente, porém gostaria de saber se tem alguma forma para fazer isso, sem colocar a mão no bolso, hehe

Comment: @FelipeStoker Nope.

Comment: eu não paguei nada ao Google, e no entanto, meu nome aparece do lado direito.

Comment: Copia a url e cola numa aba anônima

Comment: Acontece  isso se você  estiver logado, só  vai aparecer para você

Comment: Para pública não funciona, só deve funcionar só pra você.